# Angular, provider or injector, which one creates a service instance

Tags: angular, document

In Angular Document,
[where say "provider create a service instance"](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#provide-the-heroservice),

> You must make the HeroService available to the dependency injection system before Angular can inject it into the HeroesComponent, as you will do below. You do this by registering a provider. ***A provider is something that can create or deliver a service***; in this case, it instantiates the HeroService class to provide the service.

but [this say "injector create a service instance"](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#configure-an-injector-with-a-service-provider)

> ***The injector is responsible for creating service instances*** and injecting them into classes like HeroListComponent.

so, after reading the document, I have a question is which one will create a service instance, provider or injector?

This question has confused me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fast forward to the section explaining [DI in angular](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: Then check [Hierarchical DI](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

Comment: You can also read about deprecated Reflective Injectors and current Static Injector to get a more in depth understanding.

Comment: Provider uses an injector to inject/provide the service.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have understood it, is that using the `providers` array of an NgModule is actually creating a provider.

For instance, look at providers overriding :

```
providers: [{ provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceMock }]
```

As you can see, you are indeed creating a provider from that array.

I guess that writing it the "standard" way, is just a shortcut to create a provider.

The injector, on the other hand, is the one creating the instances of the class, that will be injected as dependencies into your features.

In other words, a provider would be the service decorated with `@Injectable`, and the injector would be the one calling `new MyService()`.

(Again, not sure about my explanation, that's just how I got it myself).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a service there are few things that you need.

1) Create the service
2) Get it in the component where you want it to be injected as a dependency.
3) The only way angular can instantiate the service is if you "provide" some instruction to Angular. This is what you do in providers.

`A provider is an instruction to the DI system on how to obtain a value for a dependency. Most of the time, these dependencies are services that you create and provide.`

See this in this link in Angular documentation below:
https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can see 3 blocks

- injector
- provider
- factory

As simple poo, a factory instanciate a class ( your service ), your provider is here to choose which factory to use , real class factory or mock, and injector is just the DI which decide to use provider

so at the "component" level , yes it's the injector which "instanciate" your service , just to clarify you haven't to dot it yourself.